# Stackoverflow error in Reversi game written in Haskell

Tags: debugging, haskell, functional-programming, stack-overflow

this code is causing a stack overflow error - can any of you people see anything Ive missed that could be causing it? Ive gone through all the functions and set them to just return arbitrary values but the stack overflow error is still showing up..

```
module Reversi where

import Data.List

-- Position type and utility functions
type Position = (Int, Int)

-- Given a Position value, determine whether or not it is a legal position on the board 
isValidPos :: Position -> Bool
isValidPos (a,b)
  | a > 8 || b > 8 = False
  | a < 1 || b < 1 = False
  | otherwise      = True

-- Player type and utility functions
data Player = PlayerWhite | PlayerBlack deriving (Eq)

instance Show Player where
  show PlayerWhite = "white"
  show PlayerBlack = "black"

-- Given a Player value, return the opponent player
otherPlayer :: Player -> Player
otherPlayer a
  | a == PlayerWhite = PlayerBlack
  | otherwise = PlayerWhite

-- Piece type and utility functions
data Piece = Piece Position Player deriving (Eq)

instance Show Piece where
  show (Piece _ PlayerWhite) = " W"
  show (Piece _ PlayerBlack) = " B"

-- Given a Player value and a Piece value, does this piece belong to the player?
isPlayer :: Player -> Piece -> Bool
isPlayer a (Piece (x,y) z)
  | a == z = True
  | otherwise = False

-- Given a Piece value, determine who the piece belongs to
playerOf :: Piece -> Player
playerOf a 
  | show a == " W" = PlayerWhite
  | otherwise = PlayerBlack

-- Flip a piece over
flipPiece :: Piece -> Piece
flipPiece (Piece (x,y) z)
  | z == PlayerWhite = (Piece (x,y) PlayerBlack)
  | otherwise = (Piece (x,y) PlayerWhite)

-- Board type and utility functions
type Board = [Piece]

-- The initial configuration of the game board
initialBoard :: Board
initialBoard =
  [
    Piece (3,4) PlayerWhite, Piece (4,4) PlayerBlack,
    Piece (3,3) PlayerBlack, Piece (4,3) PlayerWhite
  ]

-- Given a Position value, is there a piece at that position?
isOccupied :: Position -> Board -> Bool
isOccupied (x,y) b
  | any (\(Piece b c) -> b == (x,y)) b = True
  | otherwise = False

-- Which piece is at a given position?
-- Return Nothing in the case that there is no piece at the position
-- Otherwise return Just the_piece
pieceAt :: Position -> Board -> Maybe Piece
pieceAt (x,y) b
  | isOccupied (x,y) b = (find (\(Piece (a,b) player) -> (a,b) == (x,y)) b)
  | otherwise = Nothing

-- ***
-- Determine if a particular piece can be placed on a board.
-- There are two conditions:
-- (1) no two pieces can occupy the same space, and
-- (2) at least one of the other player's pieces must be flipped by the placement of the new piece.
validMove :: Piece -> Board -> Bool
validMove (Piece (x,y) p) b
  | isOccupied (x,y) b && toFlip (Piece (x,y) p) b /= [] = True
  | otherwise = False

-- ***
-- Determine which pieces would be flipped by the placement of a new piece
toFlip :: Piece -> Board -> [Piece]
toFlip (Piece (x,y) player) b
  | validMove (Piece (x,y) player) b = (getLineDir (-1,-1) (Piece (x,y) player) b) ++
                                       (getLineDir (-1,0)  (Piece (x,y) player) b) ++
                                       (getLineDir (-1,1)  (Piece (x,y) player) b) ++
                                       (getLineDir (0,-1)  (Piece (x,y) player) b) ++
                                       (getLineDir (0,0)   (Piece (x,y) player) b) ++
                                       (getLineDir (0,1)   (Piece (x,y) player) b) ++
                                       (getLineDir (1,-1)  (Piece (x,y) player) b) ++
                                       (getLineDir (1,0)   (Piece (x,y) player) b) ++
                                       (getLineDir (1,1)   (Piece (x,y) player) b)
  | otherwise = []

-- ***
-- Auxillary function for toFlip.
-- You don't have to use this function if you prefer to define toFlip some other way.
-- Determine which pieces might get flipped along a particular line
-- when a new piece is placed on the board.
-- The first argument is a vector (pair of integers) that describes
-- the direction of the line to check.
-- The second argument is the hypothetical new piece.
-- The return value is either the empty list,
-- a list where all pieces belong to the same player,
-- or a list where the last piece belongs to the player of the hypothetical piece.
-- Only in the last case can any of the pieces be flipped.
getLineDir :: (Int, Int) -> Piece -> Board -> [Piece]
getLineDir (x1,y1) (Piece (x,y) player) b
  | isOccupied (x*x1, y*y1) b && (pieceAt (x, y) b) == (pieceAt (x*x1, y*y1) b) = (concat . concat) (map (\(Piece (x,y) player) -> drop 1 [filter (\(Piece (x,y) player) -> (x,y) == (x*x1, y*y1))    b]++[(getLineDir (x*x1, y*y1) (Piece (x,y) player) b)]) b)
  | otherwise = []
--getLineDir :: (Int, Int) -> Piece -> Board -> [Piece]
--getLineDir (x1,y1) (Piece (x,y) player) b
--    | isOccupied (x*x1, y*y1) b && (pieceAt (x, y) b) == (pieceAt (x*x1, y*y1) b) = (Piece (x, y) player):(getLineDir (x*x1, y*y1)    (Piece (x,y) player) b)
--   | otherwise = []

-- ***
-- Auxillary function for toFlip.
-- You don't have to use this function if you prefer to define toFlip some other way.
-- Given the output from getLineDir, determine which, if any, of the pieces would be flipped.

--flippable :: [Piece] -> [Piece]
-- ***
-- Place a new piece on the board.  Assumes that it constitutes a validMove
makeMove :: Piece -> Board -> Board
makeMove p b = [p]++b

-- ***
-- Find all valid moves for a particular player
allMoves :: Player -> Board -> [Piece]
allMoves p ((Piece (x,y) plr):bs) =
   if p == plr then ( toFlip (Piece (x,y) p) [Piece (x,y) p]++bs )++(allMoves p bs)    else []

--allMoves :: Player -> Board -> [Piece]
--allMoves p b
--    | filter (\(Piece (x,y) player) -> player == p) b /= [] = (concat . concat) (map (\x -> drop 1 [filter (\(Piece (x,y) player)    -> player == p) b]++[(toFlip x b)] ) (filter (\(Piece (x,y) player) -> player == p) b))
--    | otherwise = []

-- ***
-- Count the number of pieces belonging to a player
score :: Player -> Board -> Int
score player [] = 0 score player ((Piece pos plr):bs) = if player == plr then 1 + score player bs else score player bs

-- Decide whether or not the game is over. The game is over when neither player can make a validMove
isGameOver :: Board -> Bool
isGameOver b
  | allMoves PlayerBlack b == [] && allMoves PlayerWhite b == [] = True
  | otherwise = False

-- Find out who wins the game.
-- Return Nothing in the case of a draw.
-- Otherwise return Just the_Player
winner :: Board -> Maybe Player
winner b
  | score PlayerWhite b > score PlayerBlack b = Just PlayerWhite
  | score PlayerWhite b < score PlayerBlack b = Just PlayerBlack
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

It's probably caused by a recursion that never ends. You might want to dig a bit more into `getLineDir` which recurses and it's not clear whether it's finishing or not.

You might also want to use a debugger to see track the execution of your code (see http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.4/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html).

Also, your code could be simplified. Every time you have something like :

```
f :: a -> Bool
f a | someGuard = True
    | otherwise = False
```

You could replace it by

```
f :: a -> Bool
f a = someGuard
```

Another thing, `[x]++xs` is better done like this : `x : xs`. (see `makeMove`)

A final change :

```
flipPiece :: Piece -> Piece
flipPiece (Piece (x,y) z)
  | z == PlayerWhite = (Piece (x,y) PlayerBlack)
  | otherwise = (Piece (x,y) PlayerWhite)
```

could be simplified like this for instance,

```
 flipPiece :: Piece -> Piece
 flipPiece (Piece xy PlayerWhite) = Piece xy PieceBlack
 flipPiece (Piece xy PlayerBlack) = Piece xy PieceWhite
```

Comment: Thanks for your ideas man, Im taking a break for a few hours as Ive started seeing red ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you multiplying the direction and the position? I think you need to add them!

If you want to check whether a placement on `(5,4)` is valid for Black, your code will try to compute `getLineDir (-1,-1) (Piece (5,4) PieceBlack) board`. The very first thing that will be computed is `isOccupied (-5,-4) board` and that just doesn't seem right to me - but if you replace the multiplication by addition, then `isOccupied (4,3) board` will get called.

As the code stands now, there's a lot of places where offsetting a position by a direction happens in `getLineDir`:

```
getLineDir (x1,y1) (Piece (x,y) player) b
  | isOccupied (x*x1, y*y1) b && (pieceAt (x, y) b) == (pieceAt (x*x1, y*y1) b) = (concat . concat) (map (\(Piece (x,y) player) -> drop 1 [filter (\(Piece (x,y) player) -> (x,y) == (x*x1, y*y1))    b]++[(getLineDir (x*x1, y*y1) (Piece (x,y) player) b)]) b)
  | otherwise = []
```

I would recommend breaking that logic out into something like

```
type Direction = (Int,Int)
offset :: Postion -> Direction -> Position
offset (x,y) (deltax,deltay) = (x+deltax, y+deltay)
```

Then `getLineDir` becomes (untested!):

```
getLineDir dir (Piece pos player) b
  | isOccupied (offset pos dir) b && pieceAt pos b == pieceAt (offset pos dir) b = (concat . concat) (map (\(Piece (x,y) player) -> drop 1 [filter (\(Piece (x,y) player) -> (x,y) == offset (x,y) dir) b]++[(getLineDir (offset (x,y) dir) (Piece (x,y) player) b)]) b)
  | otherwise = []
    where newPos = offset pos dir
```

I would also recommend renaming the variables you're binding in the inner lambdas, it's quite hard to see which `x`,`y` and `player` is which! But this is maybe more something for [Codereview Stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)!